# How to install PHP driver for Informix?

Tags: php, windows, xampp, drivers

In my company I am using Windows 8, IBM Informix Dynamic Server, XAMPP v3.2.1, IBM Informix Client SDK 4.10 (64-bit).
I have tried downloading php_pdo_informix.dll, php_pdo.dll, all I've got was:

> PHP Warning: PHP Startup: PDO: Unable to initialize module
>   Module compiled with module API=20050922
>   PHP compiled with module API=20100525
>   These options need to match
>
> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_informix.dll" - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Then I've downloaded PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.1.tgz and tried to compile it with:

```
buildconf --force
configure --enable-aop
nmake
```

result was:

```
'buildconf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: I have no idea how exactly work the compilation of PHP PECLs , but I already compile the Informix PDO at linux and I used the `phpize` to create the configure script... did you tried with it?

Comment: It doesn't work. Make file doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi Cikson, so far I not found anyplace with a "how to" and what needs to compile the informix pdo at windows and generate the pdo_informix.dll. The unique reference I able to give to you is this [IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0607bombardier/) which I consider useless and this [old version](http://www.iiug.org/software/index_all.html#php_pdo_informix). But what you can do is try contact the authors of this two links and ask  for some guidance...